Building VBA Macro For Excel Tasks
extremely new to VBA coding and trying to figure out how to edit the code on my macro that I recorded.
Background:
Recorded some steps to my macro that filters and sorts through data
Here is the code for what was recorded:
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    Range("A2:L2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$L$18").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="NW EMER"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$L$18").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="CBC7"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("L2:L18"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub






04/01/2024 - 04/10/2024















PT LOCATION
PT DOB
PT MRN
PT NAME
PT SEX
ORDER
ORDERCODE
COLDT
RECDT
RESDT
COLREC
RECRES


NW EMER
9/18/1997
15786990
Smith, Emily
M
Complete Blood Count (CBC)
CBC7
4/1/2024 12:04:00
4/1/2024 12:23:00
4/1/2024 12:57:00
19
34


N450
4/2/1985
16904927
Johnson, Benjamin
F
Basic Metabolic Panel (BMP)
BMP5
4/2/2024 1:23:00
4/2/2024 1:50:00
4/2/2024 2:46:00
27
56


W550
11/30/1972
90739275
Brown, Sophia
M
Troponin
TRO3
4/3/2024 12:12:00
4/3/2024 12:37:00
4/3/2024 1:32:00
25
55


W550
7/13/2000
23456789
Davis, Alexander
M
Basic Metabolic Panel (BMP)
BMP5
4/4/2024 1:48:00
4/4/2024 2:12:00
4/4/2024 2:59:00
24
47


N450
2/25/1991
87654321
Miller, Olivia
F
Troponin
TRO3
4/5/2024 8:16:00
4/5/2024 8:29:00
4/5/2024 8:59:00
13
30


NW EMER
6/8/1983
12345678
Wilson, Noah
F
Complete Blood Count (CBC)
CBC7
4/6/2024 4:43:00
4/6/2024 4:56:00
4/6/2024 5:43:00
13
47


N450
10/21/1968
98765432
Taylor, Emma
F
Troponin
TRO3
4/7/2024 3:22:00
4/7/2024 3:41:00
4/7/2024 4:14:00
19
33


W550
3/14/2005
54321098
Anderson, Liam
M
Complete Blood Count (CBC)
CBC7
4/8/2024 6:02:00
4/8/2024 6:26:00
4/8/2024 7:10:00
24
44


NW EMER
8/7/1994
98765431
Thomas, Ava
F
Basic Metabolic Panel (BMP)
BMP5
4/9/2024 10:29:00
4/9/2024 10:55:00
4/9/2024 11:32:00
26
37


NW EMER
5/26/1979
13579246
Martinez, Jacob
M
Troponin
TRO3
4/10/2024 3:45:00
4/10/2024 4:07:00
4/10/2024 4:25:00
22
18


N450
1/9/1988
24681357
Jackson, Isabella
M
Basic Metabolic Panel (BMP)
BMP5
4/1/2024 2:07:00
4/1/2024 2:34:00
4/1/2024 3:15:00
27
41


W550
12/3/1960
86420937
White, Ethan
M
Complete Blood Count (CBC)
CBC7
4/3/2024 11:05:00
4/3/2024 11:18:00
4/3/2024 12:15:00
13
57


N450
9/29/1976
72938416
Harris, Mia
F
Troponin
TRO3
4/5/2024 3:18:00
4/5/2024 3:49:00
4/5/2024 4:53:00
31
64


NW EMER
4/17/1993
10325476
Clark, William
F
Troponin
TRO3
4/7/2024 9:21:00
4/7/2024 9:57:00
4/7/2024 10:45:00
36
48


NW EMER
11/11/2002
43895761
Young, Charlotte
M
Basic Metabolic Panel (BMP)
BMP5
4/9/2024 1:00:00
4/9/2024 1:30:00
4/9/2024 2:50:00
30
80


NW EMER
9/15/1954
69072583
Rodriguez, James
F
Complete Blood Count (CBC)
CBC7
4/2/2024 4:41:00
4/2/2024 5:15:00
4/2/2024 6:21:00
34
66




Now to this code, I want to add another "step" to the macro in which it would then analyze the data that it just filtered through and on a new sheet report to me how many values there are in column L AND how many of those values are equal to or less than a value. I tried asking AI to write the code for me (ChatGPT and Claude), but regardless of how many times I ask to the AI to fix the code it wrote my macro does not function correctly and just does this after asking me to select the data:
PHOTO OF WHAT HAPPENS WHEN I TRY TO RUN MACRO
Here is the code that Claude last wrote:
Sub Macro6()

    ' Filter the data
    Range("A3:L3").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$L$19").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="NW EMER"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$L$19").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="CBC7"

    ' Sort the filtered data
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("L3:L19"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Count the number of values less than or equal to 45 in column L
    Dim countLessEqualTo45 As Long
    countLessEqualTo45 = 0
    Dim totalCount As Long
    totalCount = 0

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastRow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "L").Value <= 45 Then
            countLessEqualTo45 = countLessEqualTo45 + 1
        End If
        totalCount = totalCount + 1
    Next i

    ' Create a new sheet and record the counts
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = "Counts"
    newSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Count of values less than or equal to 45 in column L"
    newSheet.Range("A2").Value = countLessEqualTo45
    newSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Total count of values in column L"
    newSheet.Range("B2").Value = totalCount

End Sub

What I don't understand is how does this even happen? I don't even have anything within my code that would change table design????
I tried to double check the range of the rows and everything seemed like it matched? I would also like to mention that when I run the macro (press Ctrl + L) I don't actually get an error code, it just does this instead of actually doing what it I want it to.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator


Your analyze function relies on Column L. The code needs to read the values from the cells. Loading the data into an array is a good approach. Then you don't need to apply autofilter.

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowCnt As Long, ValCnt As Long
    Const CRI1 = "NW EMER"
    Const CRI7 = "CBC7"
    Const CRIVAL = 45
    Const COLVAL = 12 'Col L
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = Range("A2:L" & LastRow)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 1) = CRI1 And arrData(i, 7) = CRI7 Then
            RowCnt = RowCnt + 1
            If arrData(i, COLVAL) <= CRIVAL Then
                ValCnt = ValCnt + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Count of Rows", "Count of Values")
    Range("A2:B2").Value = Array(RowCnt, ValCnt)
End Sub



Sorry I just updated the table, as it wasnt formatting correctly does this answer still apply?

If the table header is on row2, the answer is YES. Otherwise, pls change A2 in Set rngData = Range("A2:L" & LastRow).
